# Laravel Entrust Attach Role

Tags: laravel, entrust

I am Trying to attach default role to user when a user gets register. But getting error

> ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 418: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in
>   D:\wamp\www\tornadoCms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
>   on line 63 and defined

Any Help Thanks!

Comment: Your error explains your problem

Comment: Please Explain by yourself i did not get it right yet

Comment: Well it says what the problem is, look at your code on `line 63` of `Auth\RegistersUsers.php`

Comment: Do you use a migration to create your table? Because you can use a default value for your column.